# Where did my Finder Filter go?

Tags: finder, search

Normally I'm able to filter my search by file size as shown in [this tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/17/find-large-files-in-mac-os-x-search/). However, for some reason this morning I can't find the filter anymore, where did it go?

[image]
[image]

This is what I'm expecting to see:
[image]

Thanks :)

Edit:
See the end of Tetsujin answer. Essentially the Filter won't show up when searching from "All My Files", which is at minimum, not a sensible design decision because launching Finder takes one to "All My Files" by default

So if that bothers you, it's possible to [change this senseless default](http://www.cultofmac.com/249490/quit-seeing-all-my-files-in-the-finder-change-the-default-new-window-view-os-x-tips/)

Just go into preferences and change to a different "New Finder window" and then `cmd+F` will behave as expected

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a search window, that's just a regular Finder window.

Hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>  (which will open a new Search window), or start typing something in the Search box, top right, & your filters will appear.

If you still don't see it, click the **+** top right - highlighted in green below...

[image]

You can also use it to add more filter criteria...
(Note that "no query should be required" only applies if you start from  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>  not from a regular Finder window, as your first example.

[image]

*Late discovery*
It doesn't work if you start from "All My Files"
I have no idea why.

Comment: Edited to fit your situation

Comment: ooohhh... Doesn't work if your start from "All My Files". Interesting. I've never used that option before... I **know** where my files are, I hate that 'hidden path' view.